# Graphically showing remaining time

Tags: performance, qt, time

Let's consider a user has `t` milliseconds to make a click, `0 < t < 5000`. We'd like to show graphically how much time is left. Let's assume that the user has to click the button once again within `t`.

```
property int startTime
property int fps: 40
property int t: 1000 // for example
Button
{
    id: btn
    text: "Click me!"
    onClicked: 
    { 
         text = "Click again!"
         startTime = new Date().getTime()
         timer.restart() 
    } 
}
Timer
{
    id: timer
    interval: 1000 / fps
    onTriggered: 
    {   
         var progress = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / t
         if (progress < 1)
         {
             pb.value = progress
             restart() 
         }
         else
         {
             pb.value = 1
             btn.text = "Try again"
         }
    }
}
ProgressBar
{
     id: pb
     value: 0
}
```

I'm only worried about the performance impact. The UI should always remain accesible and react quickly to the tap, since `t` can be low. If it weren't, the user could click the button within the set time but "lose", since the application wouldn't respond to the click.

Should I worry about the performance hit? Is there any option to avoid it? I expect my application to be run on low-end devices too.
I'm using Qt on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fps` is reasonable, then I think that performance won't be an issue and the UI will remain responsive.

Anyway I think it is much more *elegant* to achieve the same result using an animation... You can use a `NumberAnimation` to continuously update the value of the progress bar, and then start the animation when you want to start counting the time left...

Comment: My proposal was kinda reinventing the wheel :) Thanks!